# WebWorkers transferable object works slow after creating WebWorker instance

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker

I'm testing WebWorker transferable object. It works really fast.
[transferable object test](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/workers/transferables/index.html)

But I decided create own samples and found that it works slower than expected.

Transfer time is about 120ms into the sample by the link below. 
[Link](https://gist.github.com/blackrabbit99/c5dcf0406b41248bda15#file-webworker-transferable-objects-html)

After some investigation I decided that some browser tasks block main thread and console.time data is fake. So I replaced `run();` with 
`setTimeout(run, 0);` and data transfer time became 50ms.
But after `setTimeout(run, 200);` it became 1ms as expected.

So who can explain why?

Comment: I have the same issue, were you able to solve yours? 3 years passed though...